# Operation table, Commutative and Cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G=\{e,x,y\}$ is a group and $e$ is the identity element of this group. Using the operation table show that whether this group is commutative and cyclic or not.

This is an exercise question in my book. The thing I do not understand is the operation is not given in the question. So how will I make the operation table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, whatever this operation is, you have $ex= xe = x$ and $ey=ye=y$ so you only need to figure out what is $x^2,y^2,xy$ and $yx$?

Since order $r\ne 1$ of the element must divide the order of a group (which is $3$) we  see that $x^3=e$, so subgroup $\{e,x,x^2\}$ is equal to $G$ and thus $x^2=y$ and simillary $y^2=x$.

Now what si $xy$? It is simply $e$ since $xy= x\cdot x^2 = x^3=e$.

\begin{matrix} *&e&x&y&\\
 e&e&x&y&\\
x&x&y&e&\\
y&y&e&x&
\end{matrix}

So this group is cyclic (and commutative).

Comment: How can we show that it is cyclic

Comment: ...so subgroup $\{e,x,x^2\}$ is equal to $G$

Comment: x is generator of G so G is cyclic. Can we say like this ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: No need to use Lagrange here: $xy$ cannot be $x$ or $y$ and so must be $e$. Then, $xG=G$ implies $y=x^2$.